# How to implement Start/End Polyline with Cap shape (Buttcap/Squarecap/Roundcap)

Tags: dictionary, polyline, cap

I tried to put specific cap shape at the start and beginning of the Polyline, but can't find example of reference how to implement this. I only found this in Developers Google site [Google API Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) but still no luck how to use this for my polyline. Anyone can assist? Thank you very much for your kindness attention.

The code stopped here (updated)

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.RoundCap; // not working
```

....

```
if(lineOptions != null) {
    line = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions
        .color(Color.BLUE)
        .geodesic(true);
        line.setStartCap(new RoundCap());
}
else {
    Log.d("onPostExecute","No Polylines drawn");
}
```

What library / reference I should use?
Please help to advise

-sea-

Comment: Add more details here

Comment: What kind of detail are you referring to? My requirement is to put for example Roundcap as a start of polyline and Squarecap at the end of the polyline. If you're asking real life example, you can refer to Uber app.